# Android: NullPointerException in super Activity

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I confuse about this:
I have a BaseActivity,

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String LOG = "BaseActivity";
    protected ProductInfo playingVideo;
}
```

In mainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity implements OnClickListener{
    super.playingVideo = product;
    Log.i("Check null Product", String.valueOf(product));
}
```

The log is: ha.van.bean.ProductInfo@529bd558.
That mean product is not null.
But when  I use super.playingVideo in another activity (also extends BaseActivity), NullPointerException occur.
I don't know why?
Please help me with this.

Comment: post error log and more code which are related to the problematic portion.

Comment: If you're expecting `super.playingVideo` to be shared between classes, that is not the case.